# TableView Color resets after scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

The table view I have changes Cell background colors quite often. The colors set in `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` are fine but some colors are set after the table view loads like:

```
- (void) ChangeCellColorAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentCell inSection:0]];

cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];     


 }
```

If a cell is changed with that method it will revert back to what it was originally set to when it scrolls out of view. How can I insure it will stay the same color when I scroll out of view.

Comment: how and when do you call this method? It probably needs to be called in cellForRowAtIndexPath, when you create/reuse the cell.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` updates only the cells that are visible at that time. It would be a good idea to set the background in that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take into account how the cell loading process works: when you set the color of a visible cell and the user scrolls to a point where that cell is not visible, and then scrolls back to the original point the table view will call again `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, a new cell will be created(better said an already created cell will be reused if you are doing things correctly as I assume) and the background color you previously set will be ignored.

The solution is to know which color each cell should have in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and set the color there.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed. I dis not think it would recall `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and that was my issue. You not only answered my question but you gave me some very important knowledge. Thank You!